# How would I separate an item from a UL that is centered?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to achieve the following:

[image: what I am trying to do]

But what I am getting is this:

[image: what is happening, pain]

Here is my HTML (react JSX but is the same thing):

```html
<div className="snavbarcontainer">
            
            <div className="toplefticon">
                <a class="test" href="#"><img src={topleft} alt="Testing Logo" /></a>
            </div>

            <div className="mainIcons">
                <ul className="icons_ul">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={ILookupPupils} alt="Pupil Lookup" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IMUsers} alt="Manage Users" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IHand} alt="Coming Soon" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IMAdmins} alt="Manage Admins" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IDash} alt="Dashboard" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IDB} alt="Dashboard" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
```

And my (S)CSS:

```css
body {
    //! background-color: red; - DEBUGGING ONLY!
    margin: 0
}

.snavbarcontainer {
    background-color: black;
    width: 3.5em;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}


.icons_ul {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    
    li /* Adds property to EACH LI, not the UL itself. */{
        margin: 1em 0;
    }
}

.icons_ul {
    justify-content: center;
}

.toplefticon {
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

I cannot find out for the life of me how to do this, whether with flexbox or something else!

Thanks for your answers,
Henry

Comment: Hi! What is the problem? Is it that you need space between the SR and the second icon?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Azu but I need the SR logo at the top, but the icons centered. (please please please forget about the exit icon)

Comment: Use a flexbox for this. You can set the flex layout to _column_ and can set flex children to be placed at the top or bottom or center. [This](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) might get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.snavbarcontainer {
    background-color: black;
    width: 3.5em;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}


.icons_ul {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
 .icons_ul li{   
        margin: 1em 0;
    
}

.icons_ul {
    justify-content: center;
}

.toplefticon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 5px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin-top: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="snavbarcontainer">
            
            <div class="toplefticon">
                <a class="test" href="#"><img src={topleft} alt="Testing Logo" /></a>
            </div>

            <div class="mainIcons">
                <ul class="icons_ul">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={ILookupPupils} alt="Pupil Lookup" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IMUsers} alt="Manage Users" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IHand} alt="Coming Soon" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IMAdmins} alt="Manage Admins" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IDash} alt="Dashboard" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IDB} alt="Dashboard" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: While this approach does work, it isn't ***exactly*** centered, making it a bit off - is there a way to accurately center it vertically?

Comment: Then get the '.toplefticon' out of the container '.snavbarcontainer'. Then the rest of the icons will be vertically centered. And you could position '.toplefticon' absolutely.

Comment: This works perfectly, just going to make an edit to add padding - thank you ever so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//JSX
<div className="snavbarcontainer">

            <div className="toplefticon">
                <a class="test" href="#"><img src={topleft} alt="Testing Logo" /</a>
            </div>

            <div className="mainIcons">
                <ul className="icons_ul">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={ILookupPupils} alt="Pupil Lookup" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IMUsers} alt="Manage Users" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IHand} alt="Coming Soon" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IMAdmins} alt="Manage Admins" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IDash} alt="Dashboard" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src={IDB} alt="Dashboard" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            //added this
            <div className="bottomlefticon">
                <a class="test" href="#"><img src={bottomLeftIcon} alt="Testing Logo" /</a>
            </div>
</div>
```

```
//CSS
body {
    //! background-color: red; - DEBUGGING ONLY!
    margin: 0
}

.snavbarcontainer {
    background-color: black;
    width: 3.5em;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    //added this
    justify-content: space-between;
}


.icons_ul {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    
    li /* Adds property to EACH LI, not the UL itself. */{
        margin: 1em 0;
    }
}
```

I added the bottom left icon at the bottom of the code so there can be proper space between them.

Comment: How would I centre the icons?

Comment: Cant do it with ```justify-content: center;```

Comment: `justify-content: space-between` didn't work? You need to add the last div that I added for it to give spaces betweem the 3 divs.

Comment: How would I do it with only the 2 items for future knowledge?

Comment: Also the fact that I am probably going to scrap the bottom element

Comment: Plus, the middle elements are not actually centered for some reason?

Comment: You can make the last div empty `<div className="bottomlefticon"></div>`. Also, can you explain how they are not centered? Vertically or horizontally?